# How to mark (within a function), do stuff (that sets other marks), and then return to the original mark

Tags: emacs, elisp

Could someone please give me an example of a function that will set a mark, then do some stuff that sets additional marks elsewhere in the buffer, and then return back to the original position that was marked at the beginning of the function.

`transient-mark-mode` is enabled by default.  I tried setting the mark with `(activate-mark)` followed by `(deactivate-mark)` to push the mark into the `mark-ring`, then my function moves around the buffer archiving a todo and performing some organizational stuff and pauses for a `read-event` (at a new location where the todo was archived) to let me see that everything was done correctly, and then I used `(set-mark-command t)` to go back to where it all began.  However, `(set-mark-command t)` did not bring me back to the original mark at the beginning of the function.  Instead, `(set-mark-command t)` brought me to another mark that was inadvertently set somewhere else while the function was running.

```
(defun none (&optional default-heading)
(interactive)
(beginning-of-visual-line)
(activate-mark)
(deactivate-mark)
    (let ((lawlist-item default-heading)
            result)
        (unless lawlist-item
          (condition-case nil
              (progn 
                (org-back-to-heading t)
                (setq lawlist-item (elt (org-heading-components) 4)))
            )
         )
    (when (search-forward-regexp ":event\\|event:" (line-end-position) t)
      (replace-match "")
        (when (and (looking-at ":$\\|: ") (looking-back " "))
          (delete-char 1)))
    (org-todo "None")
    (org-priority ?E)
    (org-schedule 'remove)
    (org-deadline 'remove)
    (org-set-property "ToodledoFolder" "DONE")
    (setq org-archive-save-context-info nil)
    (setq org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/.0.data/*TODO*::* DONE")
    (org-archive-subtree)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^\* DONE" nil t)
       (condition-case err
           (progn
             (org-sort-entries t ?a)
             (lawlist-org-cleanup) )
         (error nil))
    (re-search-forward lawlist-item nil t)
    (message (format "%s -- Finished!" lawlist-item))
    (beginning-of-visual-line)
    (org-cycle-hide-drawers 'all)
    (read-event)
    (set-mark-command t)
  ))
```

Comment: Is `save-excursion` what you want?  Documentation here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html

Comment: Thanks.  I'll read up on save-excursion tonight and see if that helps me define a location in the buffer, do some unrelated stuff, and then come back to that original location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful as well: You probably do ***NOT*** want to set the mark in your Lisp code.

This is what the Elisp manual says about `set-mark`:

```
 -- Function: set-mark position

 This function sets the mark to POSITION, and activates the mark.
 The old value of the mark is _not_ pushed onto the mark ring.

 *Please note:* Use this function only if you want the user to see
 that the mark has moved, and you want the previous mark position to
 be lost.  Normally, when a new mark is set, the old one should go
 on the `mark-ring'.  For this reason, most applications should use
 `push-mark' and `pop-mark', not `set-mark'.

 Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the
 wrong purposes.  The mark saves a location for the user's
 convenience.  An editing command should not alter the mark unless
 altering the mark is part of the user-level functionality of the
 command.  (And, in that case, this effect should be documented.)
 To remember a location for internal use in the Lisp program, store
 it in a Lisp variable.  For example:

      (let ((beg (point)))
        (forward-line 1)
        (delete-region beg (point))).
```

And this is what the doc strings of both `set-mark-command` and `push-mark` say about it:

```
Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the wrong
purposes.  See the documentation of `set-mark' for more information.
```

Comment: Well, that would be me (the novice) . . . I'll give this a try tonight -- I am assuming that `beg` is my point of origin.  Essentially, I want to set `beg` and then do a bunch of unrelated stuff and then come back to `beg` when I'm all done.

Comment: In that case, just use `save-excursion`: you do not need to keep track of the starting point and return to it.  See `C-h f save-excursion`.

Comment: Well, one concept learned `(point)` and one concept to be learned `(save-excursion . . .)` -- your sample with `beg` worked perfectly -- I just turned my existing `let` into `let*` and added `(beg (point))` and then at the end of the function `(goto-char beg)`.  Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated !!!!.

Comment: For some reason, `(save-excursion . . .)` returns to the end of the previous paragraph rather than the exact location where it began.  `(point)` is right on the money.  It may have something to do with the paragraph being moved from where `(save-excursion . . .)` began.

Comment: You last sentence makes me think that's what's going on.

Comment: Okay then -- that's a wrap.  I've got two new goodies in my bag of tricks `(point)` and `(save-excursion . . .)`.  Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `save-excursion` is what you're looking for--it saves your position in the buffer (along with other information), executes the body, and returns to the original position.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll look at this tonight and see if it helps me set a position (e.g., line 3, column 5), remember it, and then come back later to that some position.

Comment: Second concept almost learned -- i.e., `(save-excursion . . . )`  I'm a little puzzled at the apparent difference between that and using `(point)`.  When using `(point)`, it was right on the money -- i.e., line 17, column 1.  For some reason, `(save-excursion . . . )` returned me to the end of the previous paragraph (end of line 15) instead of the precise location where `(save-excursion . . .)` began (line 17, column 1).  Perhaps `(save-excursion . . .)` defaults to the end of the preceding paragraph?  The paragraph where `(save-excursion . . .)` began was moved to a location further on down.

Comment: The other possibility is that `hs-hide-all` and `(org-cycle-hide-drawers 'all)` in org-mode affect `(save-excrusion . . .)`, whereas, they do not affect `(point)`.  . . .  Nope, I just tried that and the result didn't change -- it still returns to the end of the previous paragraph.  Hmmm...